# Adding event listener on star icon or Bookmark Logo of browser's

Tags: javascript

Is there any way where I can add event on the star icon/Bookmark logo of browser, so that i can add name to the website of that URL while it gets saved in the bookmark list.

Comment: You cannot add an `EventListener`. The name of the bookmark comes from the title you have set and the url comes from the actual url.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Use a sensible `<title>` in the first place.